# создаем массив result [ ] размером N - M

Tags: c#, массивы

как создать массив с интервалом [m,n] в C#

Comment: `var array = Enumerable.Range(m, n - m + 1).ToArray();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int m = 5;  // Начало интервала
int n = 10; // Конец интервала

// Создание массива с размером, равным разности конца интервала и начала интервала плюс один
int[] array = new int[n - m + 1];

// Инициализация массива значениями из интервала [m,n]
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    array[i] = m + i;
}
```